# Infinite product with zero value

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinite-product

For an infinite product $\prod a_k$ to converge we need

1. at most finitely many zero factor, let be $m$ the maximum index of them
2. $c=\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=m+1}^n a_k$ must exists, and
3. $c\ne 0$.

> My question is "Why the additional condition 3?"

Consider 
$$\tag{1}
\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{4}\cdots
$$
The $n$th partial product would be $1/n$, thus the limit is zero.
The definition above excludes (1) from the converging infinite products, but I do not understand what is bad about (1) converging to zero. There must be some consideration behind it.

**EDIT**
My question could be read as follows: What are the advantages of this definition? Is there a better (easier to develop by excluding the zero) definition ? Why is the zero limit excluded (even in case there are no zero factors)?

Comment: Where is this definition coming from ? Did you reproduce faithfully ? $\prod_{k=0}^\infty 0$ obviously converges. By the way, there is a typo in 2.

Comment: The definition (for my understanding) is from Knopp, Theory and Application of Infinite Series, p. 218, https://archive.org/details/theoryandapplica031692mbp/page/n232

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you for the typo

Comment: A single zero makes the whole product $0$, unless the rest of the products diverges to $\infty$

Comment: @Peter yes, that is correct

Comment: Therefore, usually zeros are ruled out.

Comment: @Peter Do you want to say that nowadays the definition of Knopp is NOT the usual one? His definition permits: Theorem. A convergent inf.prod is 0 iff one of its term is 0

Comment: The definition is said *in the stricter sense*, and does not allow convergence to zero just by definition (so that the general term *must* tend to $1$).

Comment: In my book, it is assumed that no zeros occur and the limit is neither zero, perhaps because of the relation we get if we take the logarithm of the product which leads to a sum. This logarithm-step of course does not work if we have a $0$. Even more restrictive, in this case we must have positive factors. But it is probably a matter of taste.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do not understand. $0\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots$ is permitted and converges to 0

Comment: @MohamedAli: to assert convergence *in the stricter sense*, you must remove the zeroes. Convergence *in the stricter sense* is not convergence in the ordinary sense.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: What's odd is that on the next page, the author asserts that "a convergent infinite product has the value $0$ iff one of its factors is $0$". If he means convergent in the stricter sense this is vacuous, and if he means convergent in the looser sense this is false.

Comment: @Peter Which is your book?

Comment: @JackM You are saying that I've definitely to look for another definition. It remain me to understand why the zero limit is excluded.

Comment: Bronstein , Taschenbuch der Mathematik (German language)

Comment: My personal understanding is that when you take the logarithm of an infinite product converging stricto sensu, it turns to a converging series. Products that tend to zero are simply *less interesting*.

Comment: @Peter Thank you. Taschenbuch! 1300+ pages, in Germany they must have very big Taschen!

Comment: @Peter It appears to me that Bronstein has the same definition: Ein unendliches Produkt heißt genau dann konvergent, wenn entweder (1.186)
mit $b\ne 0$ vorliegt, **oder diese Situation lässt sich nach Weglassen von endlich vielen Faktoren erreichen, die alle gleich null sind**. Anderenfalls heißt das Produkt divergent.

Comment: and the following paragraph is "Ein konvergentes unendliches Produkt ist genau dann gleich null, wenn ein Faktor gleich null ist.", and that is exacly what @JackM referred to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is **the definition** in all books covering infinite products.  We say $\prod \frac{n}{n+1}$ "diverges to $0$", and is not included when we say an infinite product "converges".  The reason for this definition is that **it is useful**, for example in complex analysis.

One example:  (there are many others)
$$
\sin z= z \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-{\frac {z^{2} } {\pi^2n^{2} } } \right) $$
where (for all complex $z$) it is a convergent infinite product.  Therefore, we may read the zeros of $\sin$ from it directly.  With infinite products that possibly diverge to $0$, we cannot do that.

As all mathematics students know, the principle $ab = 0 \Longrightarrow (a=0\text{ or }b=0)$ is very useful.  We want to keep this useful fact for infinite products also!  The is the first (and simplest, of many) reasons that convergence of infinite products is defined this way.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add a footnote of Pringsheim from 1888, I think the first "complete" work on the topic. He discuss exactly this question and he gives, 132 years ago, the same arguments as @GEdgar: convenience (Bequemlichkeit) and conserving the properties of a finite product.

> Pringsheim: Über die Konvergenz unendlicher Produkte. Mathem. Ann. Bd. 33, S. 119-154. 1888.

The book can be found 
https://archive.org/details/mathematischean46behngoog/page/n126

[image]

[image]

Comment: is there a translation into English?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is one common definition, because (as Gerald Edgar said) it captures certain natural useful features. On the other hand, as in the question, it certainly has some features that can generate undesirable counterexamples. Try as I might, I’ve not been able to come up with a formalization that includes all the features I want (and no more).

So, unlike other formalizations (like epsilon-delta for continuity), there is definitely an ‘artisanal’ aspect to infinite products.